# Queue audio clips with MediaPlayer android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I have a chat application. Some views in the recyclerView can be audio clips. I have set a click listener on the itemView so i can play it onClick.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                itemRecyclerCallback.onRowClicked(
                    holder.adapterPosition,
                    messageItem,
                    holder
                )
            }
```

So in the callback inside the Activity i have the player function which is as below

```
private fun startPlaying(audioFileName: Uri) {
        MediaPlayer().apply {
            try {
                setDataSource(this, audioFileName)
                prepare()
                start()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "An error occurred. Please try again!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to 

1) Play the clips automatically when they appear in the recycler (only the first time)

2) When press a clip and another one is being played i want to stop the current and start the new.
Any ideas how can i do that with MediaPlayer?